# jQuery & PHP Sessions - on an radio click

Tags: jquery, session

Basically i have two radio button inputs if value A (yes) is clicked then i want it to display the a hidden div.

If value No is clicked i want it to hide the div or do nothing if it's already hidden.

I have the above ok with the following jQuery;

```
$('.minor_yes').click(function(){
    $('.underage').slideDown(); 
});
$('.minor_no').click(function(){
    $('.underage').slideUp();   
});
```

My issue is, i am using sessions so there is some page navigation if the user navigates away from the page, it stores his selection on the form,

i.e. if the user selected yes it will still display yes.

But the div is hidden again and will not initiate on page reload.

How would i do this?

Comment: i would like to apologise if you do not understand, sometimes i think i am explaining things correctly but i am not :P  so don't be scared to say XAVIER WTH ARE YOU ON ABOUT !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use php to set the visibility of the element from your session variable:

```
<div class="underage"
     <?= isset($_SESSION['sessVar']) ? "style=\"display: block;\"" : "style=display: none;\"" ?>>Hidden content</div>
```

Comment: my inputs have the name of "minor" both of them how would i parse the value of yes or no to 'sessVar' for my statement ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming PHP..

```
<input type=radio name=minor class='minor_yes' <?php $_SESSION['minor_yes']==true?echo'Selected':echo'';?> >
<input type=radio name=minor class='minor_no' <?php $_SESSION['minor_yes']==falsee?echo'Selected':echo'';?> >

<div class="minor_yes_content" style="display:<?= isset($_SESSION['sessVar']) ? "block" : "none" ?>;"> </div>
```